# How to store image null value

Tags: c#, sql

I want to store null value when there is no image available in picture box . 
But I tried but can't do that . 
Any body can plz;

```
byte[] img = null;

FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [" + timpickervalue + "]([serialno],@img)",con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", img);
```

Comment: what about this how to store null image value leave timpickervalue:cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", img);

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
//DONE: Often, it's easier to use File class then Stream's
// If imgLoc provided, let's load img from file; otherwise assign null
byte[] img = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imgLoc) 
  ? File.ReadAllBytes(imgLoc)
  : null;

...

//DONE: string interpolation / formtting makes SQL more readable
string sql = 
  $@"insert into [{timpickervalue}] 
          values ([serialno], 
                  @img)";

//DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) { 
  //DONE: create and assign the parameter 
  //TODO: Put the right condition when Null should be assigned (I suggested null or empty)
  if (img == null || img.Length <= 0)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image, 0).Value = DBNull.Value;    
  else
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image, img.Length).Value = img;

  //DONE: do not forget to run the query
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

Comment: @sheen drung: As far as I can see `imgLoc` (path to image) can be null or empty; let's check for this possibility, see my edit.

Comment: I think the string interpolation change is ultimately harmful. The original and your code is susceptible to SQL injection. The only way to fix it will also involve undoing your change to it. And people who don't understand SQL injection may take this as inspiration to avoid parameters entirely.

Comment: @sheen drung: It's time to debug. Please, put a break point on the `byte[] img = ...` line, start the routine and inspect `imgLoc` value.

Comment: at last I figure out the error and set through like this:  if (img == null)
                {
                    imgLoc = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                    img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
                }

Comment: And thnks @DmitryBychenko for your positive reply

Comment: @sheen drung: please, do not work with streams unless you *have to*. Be careful: you have to wrap streams into `using`, i.e.: using (FileStream fs = new ...) {}`. `File.ReadAllBytes` is by far an easier approach.